# how to assign JSON variable to outer jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, variables

I am displaying a list of JSON items in a DIV. How can I re-display a particular item in 
a 2nd DIV when hovered over.

Right now, the script prints:" + data.items[i].title + " verbatim, instead of actually displaying the value.

What can be changed in the script below? Thanks in advance.

NOTE: this is a different question that my previous, as it deals with TEXT, not IMAGES.

```
$.getJSON('1zONE.json', function(data) {
    globalData = data;
    var output="<ul>";
    for (var i in data.items) {
        output += "<li><h1>" + data.items[i].title + "</h1>" + data.items[i].price + "--" + data.items[i].description.one+"</li>";
    }
    output += "</ul>";
    $("#placeholder").html(output);


    $('li').on({
        mouseenter: function() {
        document.getElementById("placeholder2").innerHTML=" + data.items[i].title + ";

        }
    });   
});
```

Here is the JSON file (1zONE.json):

```
{"items":[
        {
            "id":"1",
            "thumb":"01_sm",
            "thumb2":"01_md",
            "title":"Ray",
            "price":"Villalobos",
            "description": {
                "one":"January",
                "two":12,
                "three":2012
            }
        },
        {
            "id":"2",
            "thumb":"02_sm",
            "thumb2":"02_md",
            "title":"John",
            "price":"Jones",
            "description": {
                "one":"April",
                "two":28,
                "three":2010
            }
        },
        {
            "id":"3",
            "thumb":"03_sm",
            "thumb3":"03_md",
            "title":"Jo",
            "price":"Jo",
            "description": {
                "one":"May",
                "two":8,
                "three":2010
            }
        },
        {
            "id":"4",
            "thumb":"04_sm",
            "thumb3":"04_md",
            "title":"Jo4",
            "price":"Jo4",
            "description": {
                "one":"May4",
                "two":84,
                "three":20104
            }
        }
]}
```

Comment: This is a fairly new method for display values. You should contribute instead of voting down.

Comment: Hint: look at the syntax highlighting in your question on this line: `document.getElementById("placeholder2").innerHTML=" + data.items[i].title + ";`

Comment: No offense, but this is a really, really basic issue. You should consider taking a step back and looking into beginner-level JavaScript.

Comment: I don't know if this is 'basic', it gets tricky with dynamic variables.

Comment: The script itself isn't basic, but if you can't figure out why a variable's name instead of its contents is printed, it's too advanced for your current skill level.

Comment: i understand why, i just need help with the syntax.

Comment: It would be a lot easier for you if you atleast in the start stuck with jQuery instead of mixing all sorts of stuff into your code. If you look at one of your previous questions I'm pretty sure I posted an answer that shows how to create elements with jQuery instead of using just strings, and jQuery selectors are much nicer to look at and easier to understand, so why are you using native javascript inside jquery functions etc. that clutter up the code so much you can't see basic syntax highlighting errors ?

Comment: I will replace the js with the jQ, I just want to get a working function going firstly before I tidy up.

Comment: Also, there are not a lot of demos/tutorials out which demonstrate what I am trying to do with JSON. Any of you have links you'd like to share??

Answer (score 1):

You messed up the quotes, this:

```
document.getElementById("placeholder2").innerHTML=" + data.items[i].title + ";
```

should be this:

```
document.getElementById("placeholder2").innerHTML = data.items[i].title;
```

and as it's inside a jQuery event handler, it probably would be easier to do:

```
$("#placeholder2").html(data.items[i].title);
```

**EDIT:**

To solve the problem with iteration values not being persistent, you would need a closure, so I guess I'll write it for you ?

```
$.getJSON('1zONE.json', function(data) {
    globalData = data;
    var ul = $('<ul />');

    for (var key in data.items) {
        (function(j) {
            var li = $('<li />'),
                h1 = $('<h1 />', {text: data.items[j].title});

            li.append(h1).append(data.items[j].price + "--" + data.items[j].description.one).on('mouseenter', function() {
                $('#placeholder2').html(data.items[j].title);
            }).appendTo(ul);
        })(key);
    }
    $("#placeholder").html(ul);
});​
```

Comment: This seems to only display the last title, it is not working for the first 3. It must not be looping, any clue as to why it is not?

Comment: @user1644123 - of course, you are referencing `i`, but you're doing it outside the loop where `i` will always be the last iterated value.

Comment: I placed the 2nd function inside of the loop and am still getting the same problem

Comment: @user1644123 - added an example on how to do this sort of thing.

Comment: I tested it and it is now not showing anything inside #placeholder